# Consumer1 gets disconnected when consumer2 establishes connection with Kafka brokers in Springboot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Tech stack used: Spring boot, Spring-kafka

Scenario: We want to have multiple kafkaconsumers to be created based on the configs provided in the properties file. There can be multiple kafka clusters, where each consumer connects to different Kafka Cluster.

Consumer is created in below way:

```java
KafkaConsumer<Object, Object> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer(properties);
```

Above code is placed inside the loop and based upon list of the consumer configs specified in the properties file, consumers will be created dynamically on startup of the springboot application KafkaConsumer object will be wrapped inside another class ex: ParentService.

We create multiple ParentService objects and each service object will use one KafkaConsumer object.

ParentService1 -> KafkaConsumer1  ParentService2 -> KafkaConsumer2

Issue: When KafkaConsumer1 is created, connection to the specified brokers are established successfully. Then, KafkaConsumer2 is created successfully by connecting to another set of brokers. Now, when I call poll method KafkaConsumer1, it says Connection to brokers are disconnected. And, KafkaConsumer2 is able to poll successfully.

```java
ParentService parentService1 = new ParentService();  
KafkaConsumer consumer1 = new KafkaConsumer(properties1);

ParentService parentService2 = new ParentService();  
KafkaConsumer consumer2 = new KafkaConsumer(properties2);  

consumer1.poll();
```

I see below warnings in logs

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: Connection to node -1 (xxx) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : Bootstrap broker xxx(id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: Connection to node -2 (xxx) terminated during authentication.  This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. 

org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : Bootstrap broker xxx(id: -2 rack: null) disconnected]
```

Thanks in advance!!